# Java says I have an invalid argument, but I don't think so

Tags: java

I have a simple class that looks something like this:

```
class Foo{
    float value;

    Foo(float value){
        value = value;
    }

    Foo(Bar b){
        value = b.value;
    }
}
```

I try to create an instance of the class, passing a float to the constructor:

```
Foo f = new Foo(100f);
```

and it gives me an error:

```
Static Error: No constructor in Foo matches this invocation
    Arguments: (float)
    Expected return type: Foo
    Candidate signatures: 
        Foo(float)
        Foo(Bar)
```

Invalid argument invocation `Foo(float)` , but allowed invocations: `Foo(Float)`?  What?

What's actually causing this error?

Comment: If java thinks so, i´d say it should be right. Are you invoking this constructor from an other package? Reason beeing is that the missing `public` or `private` keyword in your contructor decleration makes it package private.

Comment: Well, `value = value;` should be `this.value = value;`

Comment: strange, this seems to work for me, which version of java are you using?

Comment: Same thing here, constructor calls with float or Float both work (JDK 1.7) .

Comment: "Invalid argument invocation Foo(float) , but allowed invocations: Foo(Float)?" Where does it say that? Post the actual code (including where you're trying to call the constructor), because I'll wager you dollars to donuts that the code you're trying to compile isn't what you've pasted in the question.

Comment: @Kayaman +5 for wagering "dollars to donuts" on OP's code

Comment: are you using DrJava?

Comment: It is poor coding to have local and global variables named the same. When you are saying `value = value;` the compiler has no idea which value you are talking about.

Comment: @wero yeah, I'm in DrJava

Comment: @blahfunk OK, I can change that

Comment: seems that DrJava has issues with the code when it runs it. I would consider this a bug in DrJava.

Comment: @blahfunk "the compiler has no idea which value you are talking about" Nonsense. It refers to the method parameter.

Comment: @wero Ah.  It seems to have a lot of those

Comment: Revoke his medical... I mean Java license.

Comment: @Andy Yeah, that's what I'd thought

Comment: @andy it compiled fine, but I am pretty sure he means `this.value = value;`. Therefore, the compiler doesn't understand what he is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make both the constructors and the class itself `public`. Also you need to link to your local field using `this.value` when you have another variable with the same name in your scope (there is a parameter called `value` and a field called `value`).

The result would be:

```
public class Foo {
float value;

public Foo(float value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Foo(Bar b){
    value = b.value;
}
}
```

Comment: I think it was because I was instantiating the classes from the DrJava command-line, which didn't have package access

Comment: since changing it to public worked (well that should have generated a different error message) i´d consider to also use a different IDE for testing purposes.

Comment: @Kevin I'd love to, but DrJava is the only one my school has

Comment: @YoungHobbit How do you know the code compiles in it's existing state? You are guessing that the call "Foo f = new Foo(30.0f);" is called in the same package, right? Well in this case it is not, thus the message.